# 1-to-1 Proactive messaging using Bot Framework 4

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I am using C# (.NET Core) with Bot Framework v4 to develop a bot service. I am a beginner to Bot Framework.

The problem statement goes as follows :

- I want to be able to Store some questions on o365 SharePoint
  subscription in a list. The data structure of the list will have a
  column containing users who are the intended audience for the
  question.
- When a question is added to the list, I want my bot to send out the
  questions to intended users on Microsoft Teams.
- Even if the user is not online to teams, I would want to send out a
  notification to the user on Teams chat, something like "Missed
  conversation".

Now, I understand, on a very beginner level, that the key here is Proactive messaging using the Bot. What I can't figure out or find on any forum articles is that how do I write my bot to go to SharePoint (could be using polling or event driven) and fetch information and then send out the fetched data to Users on personal 1-to-1 team chat?

What I have done so far is :

- I have written my SharePoint business logic to fetch information.
- The bot calls this business logic when it receives an activity from
  User. i.e. say, a user says "Hi" and the bot goes and fetches
  information from SharePoint and returns it to the user in the chat
  window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Yogesh

Comment: I think you should have made SharePoint the subject of your question, not the Bot Framework. You say "you can't figure out how to write my bot to go to SharePoint (could be using polling or event driven) and fetch information". Your current question subject will likely attract Bot Framework specialists, not those with SharePoint experience

Comment: Also, Bot Framework on .net is a regular .net web app, so you can load data you usually do in a .net web app

Comment: "you can't figure out how to write my bot to go to SharePoint" : Microsoft Graph API ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: I have already figured out the part of fetching data from sharepoint, I want to implement the part where bot pro-actively calls the fetch logic. Rather than on user Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should be able to accomplish the goals, but make sure to break this up into smaller problems when looking for assistance. You might need some other layers between the two to accomplish as well.

As you have found, proactive messages will be what you want to use from the bot side to message users without them engaging the bot first. You won't find any success (especially in Teams) if the users have never interacted with the bot before as there will need to be some sort of way for the bot to be able to know how to contact them (former conversation, etc). Please find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#state-management) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

> What I can't figure out or find on any forum articles is that how do I
> write my bot to go to SharePoint (could be using polling or event
> driven) and fetch information and then send out the fetched data to
> Users on personal 1-to-1 team chat?
>
> I have written my SharePoint business logic to fetch information. The
> bot calls this business logic when it receives an activity from User.
> i.e. say, a user says "Hi" and the bot goes and fetches information
> from SharePoint and returns it to the user in the chat window.

So; it seems like the part you are missing is an intermediate layer that does polling or such. The [proactive sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages), is just using turn events to then 'proactively' message the user back. You might have to get creative. Have some sort of other service/timerjob/serverless function that might be able to assist.

This is an article for v3, but the general idea about proactive messages is good and helps understand how to best approach proactive message paradigm and ensure a good user experience:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#send-a-dialog-based-proactive-message

Comment: Thanks @Dana V, I will look into the source links you provided and try and implement pro-active messaging using Framework 4.
Apologies for flooding too many questions altogether in a single post. I will try and break down the problem statement next time I post.

Comment: that suggestion to break-down a larger problem statement to smaller bits actually improved the implementation and bring it in line with SOLID principles.
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the above mentioned tasks. For starters I was thinking too much and the solution was simple.

I wrote an infinite loop with asynchronous call to SharePoint at regular intervals using simple Task.Delay(*milliseconds*) and push the questions proactively when found.

As for 1-to-1 messaging, I am using Teams extension for Bot Framework to store individual channel information and send messages on private chat to users as and when there is something to send based on polling functionality above.

Hope that clears the air for someone, who might be looking to achieve anything similar.

Cheers,
Y

Comment: "wrote an infinite loop with asynchronous call to SharePoint at regular intervals using simple Task.Delay(milliseconds) and push the questions proactively when found." 

-- As long as that doesn't negatively impact your application resources, then I'm glad it works!

Comment: For anyone, still looking for a way to do this. User Microsoft Flows for triggering proactive messaging. Though the infinite loop method is just fine, but it could hugely impact your web server resources if polling is not judiciously configured.