# Access Sharepoint documents from .NET core application(bot framework version 4)

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework

I am using C# (.NET Core) with Bot Framework v4 to develop a bot service. I am a beginner to Bot Framework.

The problem statement is as follows:
- Give thumbs up and thumbs down at the end of every message for feedback.
- When a user clicks on thumbs down, fetch the related documents from Sharepoint.
- Display the list of fetched docs as a carousel in the chat window.

I was able to do this using the version 3 .NET SDK. However, I have trouble replicating it in version 4 of the framework - we do not have SharePoint CSOm NuGet package available for .NET Core. hence added the dlls as suggested in https://rajujoseph.com/getting-net-core-and-sharepoint-csom-play-nice/

```
public static async Task<List<SearchContent>> SearchContent(string queryText, short resultCount)
    {
        List<SearchContent> searchResult = new List<SearchContent>();
        string SiteUrl = "https:--";
        try
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
            {
               // AccessPolicyEntry ape= getAccessPolicies();

                if (SpUserName == string.Empty || SpUserPass == string.Empty)
                {
                    await GetKeyVaultSecret();
                }

                SecureString securePassword = GetSecureString(SpUserPass);
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SpUserName, securePassword);
                KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
                keywordQuery.RowLimit = 5;
                keywordQuery.SummaryLength = 3000;
                keywordQuery.QueryText = queryText + " site:\"https://----/Deploy\"";
                SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
                ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                short counter = 0;
                foreach (var oResultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
                {
                    if (counter < resultCount)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        string optimizeSummary = OptimizeContent(queryText, oResultRow["HitHighlightedSummary"].ToString());
                        searchResult.Add(new SearchContent() { Title = oResultRow["Title"].ToString(), Summery = optimizeSummary, Path = oResultRow["Path"].ToString() });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            searchResult = null;
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "SharePointSearchService.SearchContent");
        }
        return searchResult;

    }
```

Comment: Looking at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646156/1-to-1-proactive-messaging-using-bot-framework-4/56896578#56896578, the issue seems to be solvable. However, there is no code snippet available there.

Comment: You mentioned that you added the assemblies per that other article; how is it behaving now? Are you getting an exception? I don't see any actual error or question.

Comment: Also, I _believe_ he should be using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable.dll **not** Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll. In SharePoint CSOM projects you must always have both the Client and Client.Runtime assemblies (and they should match).

Comment: I think you were right @DanaV, changing the dll helped!! Thanks

Comment: Great. I'll put it an actual answer. Please mark it as the answer so that it will be helpful to others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Portable.dll` not `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.Windows.dll`. In SharePoint CSOM projects you must always have both the `Client` and `Client.Runtime` assemblies (and they should match).